# Delphi MapiSendMail returns MAPI_E_USER_ABORT

Tags: delphi, outlook, mapi, delphi-10.4-sydney, mapisendmail

I´m calling `MapiSendMail` like this:

```
lErrorCode := MapiSendMail(0, GetModuleHandle(nil), lMessage, MAPI_DIALOG or MAPI_LOGON_UI or MAPI_NEW_SESSION, 0);
```

On my dev server (Win 2016) this returns `0` and opens a new message in outlook (standard mapi client).

However on multiple clients (Win 10 Pro, Win 11 Pro) `lErrorCode` instead has value `1`. According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mapi/nc-mapi-mapisendmailw#return-value) this means `MAPI_E_USER_ABORT`:

> The user canceled one of the dialog boxes. No message was sent.

Calling `SysErrorMessage(GetLastError))` directly after returns

> Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.

Translated:

> The specified procedure could not be found.

My guess is that `mapi32.dll` is not registered correctly or has the wrong version.
How would I test this or find another way to solve this problem?

Comment: From documentation that you linked. _The MAPISendMailW (Unicode) and MAPISendMail (ANSI) functions both send a standard message, with or without any user interaction. The profile must be configured so that either function can open the default service providers without requiring user interaction._ So are you sure that all of your clients have set up mail profile in their Outlook clients?

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, I did open a message manually on the clients beforehand

Comment: Being able top open e-Mail message doesn't mean that mail client has properly set-up profile for sending e-Mail messages. For instance on one of my computers I don't have any e-Mail client set-up and yet still if I would double click on any file with *.eml or *.msg extension it would be opened in Outlook client that ships with Windows. Some goes if some application generates e-Mail message. Are you able to send some message from client computer to yourself manually?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you call `MapiLogon()` first, and then pass the session handle to `MapiSendMail()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RemyLebeau´s comment I found the solution in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656896/10190273) when looking for `MapiLogon()`:

I set the following registry keys as string:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem\MAPI="1"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem\MAPI="1"
```

Now `MapiSendMail()` correctly opens a new message in outlook.